# How to translate (internationalize) a third-party Eclipse Plug-In?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, localization, rcp

I'm developing a RCP Eclipse-based application and it makes use of the Eclipse providing tool, p2, as of Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede).

The thing is, this application must be fully in Brazillian Portuguese, and it already is, except for the p2-related UI. And that's what I need to translate. How can I?

This is where I've been:

1. Added the "updateMenu.label", "actionSets.softwareUpdates.label"... labels to my plugin.properties. Didn't work. I found out that this was related to the previous providing mechanism (Update Manager).
2. Found the "message.properties" file inside the "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk" package. Then created a copy of it on the root of my plugin folder, left only two keys and translated them. Didn't work. I guess either this is not possible or the new file should be placed under another folder?

So, I ask, is this even possible?

I still have two options in mind:

1. Create a package with the same name of the p2 one inside my plugin and place the properties there
2. Add a sufix to the file and change the locale of the application (it hasn't been done anywhere on the code since all the other messages are in Portuguese and it's a single-language application

Any suggestions?

All the best
-Alvaro C.

Comment: For each Eclipse plug-in you're using do you include the nl1 fragment in your RCP?

Answer (score 2):

you should just add a fragment project to enhance the functionality(here the language) of your third party plug-in.

1.create a fragment project

2.set your third party plug-in as "host plug-in"

3.create your message property in this fragment

**EDIT:** See http://www.eclipse.org/babel/ for a set of existing translations and for examples of using fragments to translate .properties files.

Comment: I've tried those steps, and couldn't make it work.  
  
1. Created a fragment project  
2. Selected the org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk as host plug-in  
3. Created the messages.properties file under the same package "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk"  
4. Added the fragment project to my product feature  
  
Then, the translations didn't show up, and I checked under the plugins folder and the JAR was there, and it had the properties file.  
  
I'll check this link and look for those examples. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: I couldn't find any example over Babel. The files that I could download was only the translated packages, and none of them had any fragment.xml or whatsoever inside. I have read more on the subject, thou. And have understand its concept of contribution. Then I modified my properties files, properly renamed it to messages_pt_BR.properties, still under the same package, and added the "-nl pt_BR" argument to my product Run Configuration, but still no success. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just do the translations in Eclipse with correct fragment and package name and export the translation fragment with your product, e.g. by including it into an exported feature if product depends on features.